# ¿Cómo corrijo el error en vismodel del paquete pavo?: el rango de vision esta fuera del rango del espectro. No funciona con ningun modelo de vision

Tags: r

Estoy usando el paquete pavo para analizar espectros de reflectancia de flores. Quiero hacer un tetrahedro con distintos modelos de visión pero me da un error

> Error in vismodel(spectra, visual = "avg.uv", illum = "ideal", vonkries = T) :
> wavelength range in spectra and visual system data do not match

El rango de mis datos fue establecido de 300-700, o sea que no debería estar afuera del sistema de visión uV de aves (avg.uv). De todas maneras, me da el mismo error con cualquier sistema visual que pruebo

Pego abajo el código, usados con típicos datos de espectros extraídos con un espectrofotómetro portátil (OceanOptics)

```
#Leo espectros y los suavizo

setwd("C:/Users/usuario/Documents/ColorFloresMardel/")

spectra = read.table("DatosColorMardel_todos_text.txt", header = TRUE, dec = ",", sep ="\t", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)#, na.strings = "")

spectra = as.data.frame(spectra)

spectra = as.matrix(spectra)

spectra = ifelse(spectra<0, 0, spectra)

spectra = as.data.frame(spectra)

spectra = as.rspec(spectra, interp = FALSE, lim = c(300, 700))

spectra.smooth = procspec(spectra, opt = "smooth", span = 0.25)

summ = summary(spectra.smooth)

#armo variable de UV por separado

UV = colMeans(spectra[308:479,-1])

#identifico la estructura de los nombres de mis mediciones para separar por sierra, por 
especie, por planta individual y por estructura de la flor

sierra = substr(x = colnames(spectra.smooth)[-1], start = 1, stop = 3)

spp = substr(x = colnames(spectra.smooth)[-1], start = 5, stop = 10)

indiv = substr(x = colnames(spectra.smooth)[-1], start = 11, stop = 12)

structure = substr(x = colnames(spectra.smooth)[-1], start = 18, stop = 20)

#Calculo brightness, hue y chroma, sumo el UV medido por separado y los convierto a numérico o factor, según corresponda, porque los lee como texto

BHS = as.data.frame(cbind(spp, structure, summ$B2, summ$H1, summ$S8, UV))

colnames(BHS) = c("Spp", "Structure", "B2", "H1", "S8", "UV")

BHS$B2 = as.character(BHS$B2)

BHS$B2 = as.numeric(BHS$B2)

BHS$H1 = as.character(BHS$H1)

BHS$H1 = as.numeric(BHS$H1)

BHS$S8 = as.character(BHS$S8)

BHS$S8 = as.numeric(BHS$S8)

BHS$UV = as.character(BHS$UV)

BHS$UV = as.numeric(BHS$UV)

BHS$Spp = as.character(BHS$Spp)

BHS$Spp = as.factor(BHS$Spp)

BHS$Structure = as.character(BHS$Structure)

BHS$Structure = as.factor(BHS$Structure)

#Calculo promedio por especie de planta

BHS_meansB2 = aggregate(BHS$B2, by = list(BHS$Spp), FUN = "mean")

BHS_meansH1 = aggregate(BHS$H1, by = list(BHS$Spp), FUN = "mean")

BHS_meansS8 = aggregate(BHS$S8, by = list(BHS$Spp), FUN = "mean")

BHS_meansUV = aggregate(BHS$UV, by = list(BHS$Spp), FUN = "mean")

BHS_means = cbind(BHS_meansB2, BHS_meansH1[,-c(1)], BHS_meansS8[,-c(1)], 

BHS_meansUV[,-c(1)])

colnames(BHS_means) = c("Spp", "B2", "H1", "S8", "UV")

#Intento graficar el tetrahedro (esto es lo que no me sale)

vm.uv<-vismodel(spectra,visual="avg.uv",illum="ideal",vonkries=T)

tcs.uv<-colspace(vm.uv, space = "tcs")

tcs.uv

plot(vm.uv)


#vis.flowers<-vismodel(spectra,visual="apis") 

#tri.flowers<-colspace(vis.flowers,space="tri") 

sum.flowers<-summary(tcs.uv)

plot(tcs.uv)
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Perdon, esto que lenguaje seria???

Comment: Es en R, perdón